# How do I include xsd Schema files in a visual c# project?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, sharepoint, xsd

I'm working on a library with a couple of webparts for Sharepoint 2010. One of them needs to contact Lombardi BPM to get information. The RESTful API returns xml data, which seem to need a schema. I've found where the xsd files are located within my Lombardi installation, but how do I include them in my C# library to use them when reading the XML data?

Comment: Please be clear: Do you just want to have the XSDs registered in VS so you can visually validate them or do you want to have your software do a validation on the XMLs?

Comment: How would you include an image? A text file? Or anything else that doesn't need to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should copy those .xsd files to \Xml\Schemas
(or to your solution)